# LINQ - Select the elements from array A depending on values on Array B

Tags: arrays, linq, select

Let say we have two arrays:

```
DateTime[] wDates = new DateTime[20000];
double[] wValues = new double[20000];
```

Those two arrays are both sequentially ordered, that is given an int i, wValues[i] is for the date wDates[i].

Let us say we need to get the average value of wValues where the month of the date is January

using a standard loop this would be:

```
double wAvg = 0.0;
int wDataCount = 0;
for (int i=0; i < 20000; i++)
  if (wDates[i].Month == 1)
  {
    wAvg += wValues[i];
    wDataCount++;
  }

if (wDataCount > 0)
  wAvg /= wDataCount;
```

I am wondering how to do this in LINQ?
I could create a struct/class DateDouble that contains both values and then do something like:

```
List<DateDouble> wListData = new List<DateDouble>();
Add the items...
double wAvg = (from d in wListData
               where d.Date.Month == 1
               select d.Value).Average();
```

but creating thousands of DateDouble object would be a big memory overhead when done dozens of millions time a day. The same would happen with temporary objects and trying to use 'index' and joining the index on the arrays would create awful performances.

Is there a better way to achieve this in LINQ?

Thanks,
MM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an overloaded version of IEnumerable.Where() extension method which also considers the index in the predicate.

```cs
double average = wValues.Where((d, i) => wDates[i].Month == 1).Average();
```

Comment: Thank you. This is a very elegant solution!

Answer (score 3):

Well, you can use the `Zip` operator to make things simpler:

```
var average = wDates.Zip(wValues, (date, value) => new { date, value })
                    .Where(pair => pair.date.Month == 1)
                    .Average(pair => pair.value);
```

That will still create one instance of the anonymous type per pair, but I would personally let that go and *measure* the performance before you *assume* it will be too expensive. Note that this will operate in a streaming fashion - so although it will generate a lot of garbage, the total memory required at any one time is small.

You can make it more efficient by creating your own pair *struct*... that would avoid creating extra objects, but it would be a bit more of a pain. Not *too* bad, though:

```
// The normal Tuple types are classes.
public struct TupleValue<T1, T2>
{
    private readonly T1 item1;
    private readonly T2 item2;

    public T1 Item1 { get { return item1; } }
    public T2 Item2 { get { return item2; } }

    public TupleValue(T1 item1, T2 item2)
    {
        this.item1 = item1;
        this.item2 = item2;
    }
}

var average = wDates.Zip(wValues, (date, value) => 
                                   new TupleValue<DateTime, double>(date, value))
                    .Where(pair => pair.Item1.Month == 1)
                    .Average(pair => pair.Item2);
```

I would only do this *after* proving that the first approach was two expensive though.

Comment: Why not use KeyValuePair<T1,T2> ?

Comment: @ivowiblo: Because it's not really a key/value pair? Yes, it would work - but it would give the impression that the date was some sort of key, and we don't have any evidence for that from the question. It *may* be a key, but it may not be.

Comment: The Zip operator makes sense. But the memory / assignments costs which I really wish to avoid means I am stuck with loops I guess. Thanks!

Comment: You have a value for each date, it looks like a key-value pair. Also, you are avoiding creating a new struct (that even you think is the worst part of the solution you've given). so...

Comment: @MichaelMoreno: Why? The bottom form avoids creating any new object instances at execution time... why would you use a manual loop?

Comment: @ivowiblo: What makes you sure that each date is unique? All we know is that they form a pair - I'd rather not make any assumptions (nor leave those assumptions in code) that they represent normal key/value pairing.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
double wAvg = wDates.Select((d,i) => new { Month = d.Month, Index = i })
                    .Where(x => x.Month == 1)
                    .Select(x => wValues[i])
                    .Average();
```

Anyway, in this case you will also be creating N instances of that anonymous type.

Comment: Thanks. Yes I wish to avoid to create the anonymous object.